# SQL, присвоение результата Concat_WS переменной

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #AnswersList(
    alID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
    Answer varchar(400),
    Question varchar(1000)
)
--Часть кода где я заполняю таблицу я пропущу, дабы не загромождать

DECLARE @i INT, @value varchar(5000)
SET @i = 0;
SET @value = '';

SET @value = CONCAT_WS(':',@value,(SELECT Answer FROM #AnswersList WHERE alID = 1), ' / ' ,(SELECT Question FROM #AnswersList WHERE alID = 1));
SELECT @value AS Result
```

Вот что получается в итоге:
:???????? (?????????? ????????/???????? ??????????): / :1. ????????? (??????????) ???????/???????:

При этом если я пишу следующее:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(':',@value,(SELECT Answer FROM #AnswersList WHERE alID = 1), ' / ' ,(SELECT Question FROM #AnswersList WHERE alID = 1))
```

То все ок и выводит текст, который мне нужен. Вообще я тут делаю цикл в котором каждый раз дополняю строку @value новыми значениями из таблицы #AnswersList, делая конкатенацию текущего значения value с следующей комбинацией  Answer и Question.

Подскажите, почему когда я присваиваю переменной результат конкатенации, у меня выводит знаки вопроса? мб что-то не так с самим типом данных, которые возвращает конкатенация и типом данных переменной?

Comment: Кажется, вам нужно изменить тип данных VARCHAR (..) на NVARCHAR (...)

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.